# How to switch to Live Mode DHL plugin?

Tags: magento-1.9, plugin, dhl

I'm having an issue trying to use DHL plugin in Magento 1.9.

I have introduced all the fields with the DHL information but when I'm trying to buy an item it says:

> "This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to
>   ship using this shipping method, please contact us."

I've found that I need to switch from Test mode to Live mode but I can't find where I can do that (I'm using production URLs given by DHL).

Regards.

Comment: what will you enter in shipping address?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal I've tried with multiple addresses, but when I click on "Estimate" it gives me that error. (i.e: United States, NY)

Comment: Try using different IP address.. May be its networking issue which is blocking DHL response.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal I've did that already, from three different locations, even on VPN  and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, it seems to be using test mode if nothing is specified in `Gateway URL` field at the admin panel.

[image: Magento DHL Live Mode / Test Mode]

```
// app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php:534

     $url = $this->getConfigData('gateway_url');
                    if (!$url) {
                        $url = $this->_defaultGatewayUrl;
                    }
```

You can see references to this in:

```
// app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Dhl.php:96::

protected $_defaultGatewayUrl = 'https://eCommerce.airborne.com/ApiLandingTest.asp';
```

and in:

```
// app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml:224
```

Comment: That's the post I saw before, but the credentials provided by DHL gives both test and production URLs and is what they say every time I ask for help, that I have to use the production one.

I'm using the production but for some reason it give me error, as you can see in the answer it says to change from test mode to live mode, not sure if he's referring to a Magento feature or DHL Plugin feature or the URLs  given by DHL.

Comment: I just updated my answer with some information I found looking at the core files. Hope it helps